# Execute a Method in a Webpage using C#

Tags: c#, web-services

How can I invoke a Method in a Webpage using C# code?
For eg I have to execute the search Method of "google.com" using C# method.

I was able to connect to a web page using following code

```
  string url = @"url";
            WebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
            using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
            {
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    string urtltext = reader.ReadToEnd();

                }
```

but the web page i am using has a Invoke method which i need to execute using C#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not by any way a suggestion, but I suppose this is what you want to do.

Google search page is using ajax to bring you some results. Therefore you should first see what the search button calls. I suppose (haven't looked at it) it calls some web service giving the search words as argument, or using the URL query string as an argument. Then this service returns the results as a collection of objects (probably JSON) and these objects are displayed.

Therefore, you should find which is the service called (easy if you inspect the google page code) and call it directly using a web request, similar to the one you give as an example.

This solution, is heavily depended on google's implementation. You shouldn't do it, because if google changes something on the web service returning the results, or the way it is called, then you should change your implementation too. You should see if google is providing an API for searches (I doubt it provides it for free).

Hope I helped!